# remove header view by scrolling a listview in Android

Tags: android, listview, scroll, touch

I have a ListView and a RelativeLayout as a header view.
I want to remove the header, when scroll down and move the listvit to the top of my activity. when listview scroll down, show the header and move listview below the header again. here is my code.
whats the problem?

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rltHeader"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/rltfullHeaderContainer">
  </RelativeLayout>
 <ListView

        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="16dp"


        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/brows_btn_right_left_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/brows_btn_right_left_margin"

        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:id="@+id/listViewServices"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rltfullHeaderContainer" />
```

my java code is:

```
   float  CurrentVerticalPosition=0,preVerticalPosition;

 listViewServices.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                {
                    CurrentVerticalPosition = event.getY();

                    if (CurrentVerticalPosition > preVerticalPosition + 5)
                    {
                        if (!controlsVisible)
                        {
                            Log.e("scroll Down", "AAA");
                            showViews();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (CurrentVerticalPosition < preVerticalPosition)
                    {
                        if (controlsVisible)
                        {
                            Log.e("scroll UP", "BBB");
                            hideViews();
                        }
                    }

                    preVerticalPosition = CurrentVerticalPosition;
                    return false;
                }
            });


 private void hideViews()
    {
        controlsVisible=false;

        rltHeader.animate().translationY(-rltHeader.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2));

        rltfullHeaderContainer.animate().translationY(-rltfullHeaderContainer.getTop()-rltTitleContainer.getTop()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2)).start();

       listViewServices.animate().translationY(rltTitleContainer.getHeight()-listViewServices.getTop()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2)).start();

      //listViewServices.setPadding((int)(d*14),(int)(d*2),(int)(d*14),(int)(d*3));

    }

    private void showViews()
    {
        controlsVisible=true;

        rltHeader.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));
        rltfullHeaderContainer.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2)).start();
       listViewServices.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2)).start();


        //listViewServices.setPadding((int)(d*14),(int)(d*100),(int)(d*14),(int)(d*3));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern is called a '[Quick Return Bar](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt)', as described in Roman Nurk's Google+ post and implemented in [this code](https://gist.github.com/imminent/4576886).